# Could not deduce (Semigroup (Optional a)) arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration

Tags: haskell

The following code from "Haskell Programming: From first principles" fails to compile:

```
module Learn where
import Data.Semigroup
import Data.Monoid

-- Exercise: Optional Monoid
data Optional a = Nada
                | Only a
                deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Monoid a => Monoid (Optional a) where
 mempty = Nada
 mappend Nada Nada = Nada
 mappend (Only a) Nada = Only $ mappend a mempty
 mappend Nada (Only a) = Only $ mappend mempty a
 mappend (Only a) (Only b) = Only $ mappend a b
```

It gives the following error:

```
intermission.hs:11:10: error:
    • Could not deduce (Semigroup (Optional a))
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
      from the context: Monoid a
        bound by the instance declaration at intermission.hs:11:10-40
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Monoid (Optional a)’
   |
11 | instance Monoid a => Monoid (Optional a) where
   |
```

In order to stop ghc from complaining, I had to create a semigroup instance of Optional a and define "<>". This doesn't quite make sense to me and was wondering if there was something I was overlooking.

Comment: `mappend a mempty` can be simplified to just `a`, according to the monoid laws.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

"[NOTE: Semigroup is a superclass of Monoid since base-4.11.0.0.](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html)"

The list of superclasses in has been evolving slowly.  As new useful classes are proposed, the API for older classes is updated to reflect their relationships.  This has the unfortunate effect of breaking older code.  Base 4.11.1.0 was released in April of 2018 with this breaking change to Monoid.

Comment: Is there a way to create a monoid instance without creating a dummy semigroup instance of Optional a?

Comment: @jarvin: In other words, you should define `<>` in a `Semigroup` instance using the definition you currently have for `mappend`, and define `mempty` in a `Monoid` instance. You can just ignore `mappend` since it’s only around for compatibility reasons now, and its default implementation is `mappend = (<>)`.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the solution:

```
import Data.Monoid

data Optional a = Nada | Only a deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Monoid a => Monoid (Optional a) where
   mempty = Nada

instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (Optional a) where
  Nada <> (Only a) = Only a
  (Only a) <> Nada = Only a
  (Only a) <> (Only a') = Only (a <> a')
  Nada <> Nada = Nada

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ Only (Sum 1) `mappend` Only (Sum 1)
```

Comment: I have no real understanding of Haskell, but can you elaborate your solution? Point to the lines which will solve the problem? Or which lines didn't work. It is easier to grasp for people trying to understand the problem instead of just copy pasting your answer in their code.

Comment: @Fjarlaegur the part that solves the issue is `instance Semigroup`. In the OP's code, he has an instance of Monoid, just like Chandan's answer here. The difference is that Chandan has also added the instance of Semigroup. As John F. Miller answered, having an instance of Monoid used to be enough, but now things have changed and you also need an instance of Semigroup.

However, the logic in the OP's instance of Monoid is the same as the logic in Chandan's instance of Semigroup (don't be confused by `mappend` vs `<>`, they are the same thing).