# How to solve a Haskell code error "<>' is not a (visible) method of class `Monoid'"?

Tags: haskell, monoids, semigroup

Lets see declaration of a new data type used to deal with reverse list in Haskell:

```
import Data.Monoid 
data RevList a = Nil | RCons (RevList a) a deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Monoid a => Monoid (RevList a) where
    mempty = Nil

instance Semigroup a => Monoid (RevList a) where
    Nil <> RCons (RevList a) a = RCons (RevList a) a
    RCons (RevList a) a <> RNil = RCons (RevList a) a
    Nil <> Nil = Nil
```

The problem I'm troubled with is a compilation failure which description looks as follows:

```
 `<>' is not a (visible) method of class `Monoid'
```

First I've tried to create a Monoid instance without any declaration of a Semigroup instance, but it caused another failure managed after reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237895/could-not-deduce-semigroup-optional-a-arising-from-the-superclasses-of-an-in). So, what's wrong with '<>' in the current stuff? Be sure, I'm aware of missing Monoid function like mappend or mconcat to be added to Monoid instance code as compulsory ones.

Answer (score 5):

The instance defining `<>` should be for `Semigroup (RevList a)`, not for `Monoid (RevList a)`, because `<>` is a `Semigroup` method.

> I'm aware of missing Monoid function like mappend or mconcat to be added to Monoid instance code as compulsory ones

They aren't actually compulsory, you can tell this from

> Minimal complete definition
>
> ```
> mempty
> ```

in http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html.

You also aren't actually using the constraints in your instances (the part before `=>`); e.g. you aren't calling `mempty :: a` in your implementation of `mempty :: RevList a`. So they can be removed and you end up with

```
instance Monoid (RevList a) where
    mempty = RNil

instance Semigroup (RevList a) where
    RNil <> RCons (RevList a) a = RCons (RevList a) a
    RCons (RevList a) a <> RNil = RCons (RevList a) a
    RNil <> RNil = RNil
```

Answer (score 1):

```
instance Semigroup [a] where
   (<>)  =  (++)
```

saves us having to define

```
append (x:xs) ys  =  x : append xs ys     -- x is the first
append    []  ys  =                ys
```

Treating the same regular list data type `(x:xs)` as the representation of the reversed list with `x` at its end, we'd have to define:

```
apprev xs (y:ys)  =  y : apprev xs ys     -- y is the last
apprev xs    []   =             xs
```

(so that, actually, `apprev == flip append`! -- i.e. we're basically just looking at the same thing in a mirror.)

A type is defined by its interactions, not representation. There's no need for a completely new data type definition if the old one is exactly isomorphic to the new (can represent it just fine). Just a `newtype` tag will suffice, to signal the different behavior on appends:

```
newtype RevList a  =  Rev [a]

instance Semigroup (RevList a) where
   Rev xs <> Rev []      =  Rev xs
   Rev xs <> Rev (y:ys)  =  Rev (y:zs) 
                              where 
                              Rev zs  =  Rev xs <> Rev ys
```

(a side note: your definition does not handle all possible cases. it also mixes `Nil` and `RNil` up.)